# use lodash operators in nested properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, grouping, lodash

I have array of objects

```
{
  "agent_name": "AgentName",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "date": "Tue, 1 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count":[
         {
           "count": 5,
           "intent": "intent1"
         },
         {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
         },
         {
           "count": 0,
           "intent": "intent3"
         },
       ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Tue, 2 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count":[
         {
           "count": 5,
           "intent": "intent1"
         },
         {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
         },
         {
           "count": 0,
           "intent": "intent3"
         },
       ]
    },
    ... the same for the next days of month
  ]
}
```

I need to get the sum of count for each intent grouped by date.

The result should be something like this:

```
[10, 2, 0]
```

where 10 correspond to sum of count field of the intent 'intent1' during all days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first flat and select the required array "analytics". Then use groupBy and sum to get the final result.

```js
let data = {
  "agent_name": "AgentName",
  "analytics": [
    {
      "date": "Tue, 1 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count":[
         {
           "count": 5,
           "intent": "intent1"
         },
         {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
         },
         {
           "count": 0,
           "intent": "intent3"
         },
       ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Tue, 2 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count":[
         {
           "count": 5,
           "intent": "intent1"
         },
         {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
         },
         {
           "count": 0,
           "intent": "intent3"
         },
       ]
    },
  ]
}

let flatResult = _.flatMap(data.analytics, 'intents_count');
let result = _(flatResult).groupBy('intent').map(x => _.sumBy(x, 'count'));
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what about the last day, the last 7 days ? How to use the limit operator for example ?

Comment: Do u mean, you need all the records for last 7 days and then calculate the sum? you can use _.filter to filter out the data then use that variable in _.flatMap. try this code.... let filteredData = _.filter(data.analytics, x => { 
  let today = new Date();
  let todayMinus7Days = today.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
  return new Date(x.date) > todayMinus7Days
});

Comment: Then you can pass filteredData instead of data.analytics in flatMap.. something like this... let flatResult = _.flatMap(filteredData, 'intents_count');

Answer (score 2):

I have a high level solution to what can be done. This is not using lodash operators, but can be a good starting point.

```js
const data = {
  "agent_name": "AgentName",
  "analytics": [{
      "date": "Tue, 1 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count": [{
          "count": 5,
          "intent": "intent1"
        },
        {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
        },
        {
          "count": 0,
          "intent": "intent3"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Tue, 2 Aug 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
      "intents_count": [{
          "count": 5,
          "intent": "intent1"
        },
        {
          "count": 1,
          "intent": "intent2"
        },
        {
          "count": 0,
          "intent": "intent3"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const arr = [];

data.analytics.forEach(intentObj => {
  intentObj.intents_count.forEach(obj => {
    //calculating the index to store the value in array.
    const index = obj.intent[6] - 1;
    if (arr[index] !== undefined) {
      arr[index] = arr[index] + obj.count;
    } else {
      arr[index] = obj.count;
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```